# Group By alternative in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a table **Schedule** with 3 columns (**id, ref_number, pay_date**). Each ref_number has a pay_date in every month. So the table looks something like this:

```
id | ref_number | pay_date
-----------------------------
1  | A001       | 2018-06-29
1  | A001       | 2018-07-29
1  | A002       | 2018-06-30
1  | A002       | 2018-07-30
1  | A002       | 2018-08-30
1  | A003       | 2018-06-29
```

I want to fetch only the earliest record for every ref_number that have pay_date between today and a date (30 or 31 days from today). The below query works fine in Mysql (I would pass the dates dynamically later).

```
 SELECT id,ref_number,MIN(pay_date) FROM schedule
 WHERE  (pay_date BETWEEN '2018-06-30' AND '2018-07-30')
 GROUP BY ref_number
```

I know we can turn the mysql "strict" to false in Database config file and the Group By would behave as expected, but without having to change that is there any other way around this problem?

What would be the eloquent equivalent for this query? With or without groupby.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a while, I came across an answer using **nested select** statement and gave it a try in Laravel. It worked exactly as I wanted. Here's the sweet piece of code:

```
Schedule::select(DB::raw(id, ref_number, MIN(pay_date) as pay_date))
          ->from(DB::raw("(SELECT * 
                       FROM schedule 
                       WHERE (pay_date > CURDATE())) 
                       temp")
                      )
          ->groupBy('temp.ref_number')
          ->get();
```